# Copy data activity in ADF is not deleting data in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-data-factory

Right now, I am using ADF CopyData activity to copy the data from Azure SQL to Azure Table Storage.

**It is inserting/Replacing/Updating data data while loading the data by triggering that ADF pipeline. This operation will take care by "Insert type" option which is having in Sink of CopyData activity.
But, It is not deleting the records in destination(ATS table).**

How to sync Azure SQL data with Azure Table Storage(for deleted data as well)

[image]

Ex:
**Source SQL table: Employee**

```
Id    Name
1     User1
2     User2
```

Now, using this copy data, these 2 data synced in ATS
Destination ATS Table: Employee

```
PartitionKey   RowKey    Timestamp         Name
1              NewGuid   2022-07-22 11:30  User1
2              NewGuid   2022-07-22 11:30  User2
```

Now, in Source SQL table getting updated as below,

```
Id    Name
1     User2
3     User3
```

Now, Id 2 got deleted and Name udpated for Id 1 and Added Id 3.

Again If I run pipeling, ATS updated as below,

```
PartitionKey   RowKey    Timestamp         Name
1              NewGuid   2022-07-22 12:30  User2
2              NewGuid   2022-07-22 11:30  User2
3              NewGuid   2022-07-22 12:30  User3
```

Now, here PartitionKey 2 is not deleted. but Insert and Update as done.

How to delete this record as well using Copy Data activity sync.?

Comment: You want to trigger the pipeline to delete the data in table storage for every deletion in your source (SQL table)?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT: Please check my updated example. I want to sync source SQL data with Destionation ATS data

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and I got same result.

**AFAIK**, Copy activity did not delete any data from any target. It will **overwrite the data in target with the source data**. 
In the Sink settings also, it is mentioned as **insert type**.

But here, the Azure Table storage supports update or replace (we can assume it as delete as old data deletes) of data from outside only when the new record's **Partition Key and RowKey** matches with the records in Target.

That is not happening here with your last row. That's why it is not updating.

You can raise the feature request for the deletion using Copy activity for this type of storage [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

You can try this manual approach to delete that kind of records when your data is **small**.

- Create a new **Unique Column only for the RowKey** of Table storage. Assign your **regular table Id to partition key** and this for rowkey. So, whenever you want to delete old records and update new ones, give this old RowKey value to that.